# What does $C^1([0,1])$ mean?

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, continuity, differential-topology

I know this question has been asked a lot, but please bare with me as there is a nuance that has confused me.

I thought I understood the definition of $C^1([0,1])$. However, I recently asked a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4688359/can-i-extend-a-c1-function?noredirect=1#comment9918533_4688359) and the comments made me realise I may have a fundamental misunderstanding. I have always thought that $f \in C^1([0,1])$ meant that $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and is continuously differentiable on $[0,1]$.

However, as noted to me in the comments on the referenced question, I've realised I don't understand what it means to say a function is continuously differentiable on a closed set. Which of the following does it mean:

1. $f$ is continuously differentiable on $(0,1)$ and the left and right derivatives of $f$ exist at $0$ and $1$, respectively, and the resulting derivative is continuous on $[0,1]$.
2. There is an open set $U$ containing $[0,1]$, over which $f$ is continuously differentiable.

Or, are the statements $(1)$ and $(2)$ equivalent? The reason I ask is that I always assumed the former definition was correct, and therefore I thought that for an arbitrary compact set, $T\subset \mathbb{R}^N$, you could say something similar like:

$$\textbf{(1*)} \quad f \in C^1(T) ~\text{ iff } ~f \text{ is continuously differentiable on Int}(T) \text{ and, for any}$$

$$\text{ sequence of points tending to }\partial T\text{ the limit of the}$$

$$\text{ derivative at those points is well defined and is a continuous$$
$$\text{ extension of the derivative on Int(}T) $$

with the statement being vacuously true for isolated points of $T$. However, I now realize this isn't standard, and the texts I have been referring to have been a little ambiguous on this point (for instance in page 22 of [this text](https://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/%7Efeng/papers/Random_Fields_and_Geometry_%5BAdler%5D.pdf)). An alternative notion for compact $T$ based on statement $2$ above could have been given by:

$$\textbf{(2*)} \quad f \in C^1(T) ~\text{ iff } ~\exists \text{ an open }T'\supset T, \text{ such that }f \in C^1(T')$$

Would $\textbf{(1*)}$ and $\textbf{(2*)}$ be equivalent (and if not, what is a counterexample)? It seems to me that $\textbf{(1*)}$ resembles the conditions of Whitney's Extension Theorem in some way, and $\textbf{(2*)}$ in some way resembles how differentiability is defined on a smooth manifold with boundary that is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$ (in the sense of John Lee's [Introduction to Smooth Manifolds](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4419-9982-5)).

Comment: I may be wrong, and someone please correct if so, but I thought that this was the set of continuous functions with the 1-norm, which are continuous of the space $[0,1]$

Comment: Regarding page 22 of the linked text, I did not see any definition of $C^1$ on that page.

Comment: @Luthier415Hz: The function space you refer to is usually denoted $C^0[0,1]$. In general the $C^n[0,1]$ notation refers to a space of functions $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ which are $n$-times continuously differentiable, with norm induced by all of the sup norms. So the topology on $C^1[0,1]$ is induced by the sup norm on $f$ and the sup norm on $f'$.

Comment: Apologies, this was an error on my part missing the continuity; i will now fix that.

Comment: Thanks Lee, one time my professor in Functional Analysis wrote $C^2[a,b]$ and said "This is the 2 norm", not the number of differentiations. Is there a way to spot the difference?

Comment: $L^2[a,b]$ is certainly the 2-norm $\sqrt{\int |f|^2 dx}$. I've always seen $C^2[a,b]$ as twice-continuously-differentiable functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close, but not quite there (or perhaps you just took too many shortcuts in writing $1$ and $2$). Replace $1$ by this:

> $1'$: $f$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$, the right derivative exists at $0$, the left derivative exists at $1$, and the resulting function $f' : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ is continuous.

Also, replace $2$ by this:

> $2'$: There is an open set $U \subset \mathbb R$ containing $[0,1]$ and an extension of $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ to $f : U \to \mathbb R$, such that $f$ is differentiable on $U$ and $f' : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ is continuous.

With those corrections, $1'$ and $2'$ are equivalent, and each of them is (by definition in the case of $1'$) equivalent to $f \in C^1[0,1]$.

Other equivalent variations are possible. For example in $2'$ the closing clause could be replaced by "$f' : U \to \mathbb R$ is continuous" in this position, and the statement would still be equivalent.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2243393/386889) (for a reformulation of $1'$).

Comment: Apologies, I realised i missed the continuity of f' in my descriptions; thank you. What about the generalisation to arbitrary compact T, does the equivalence still hold there?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is good learn from an example to understand such kind of concepts well.

Let $f(x) = x^2 \sin (1/x)$ if $x > 0$ and $f(0)=0$.
Then $f$ is continuous, continuously differentiable on $x> 0$.

At $x = 0$,
$$
\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} = h \sin (1/h)
$$

implies the right derivative exists and is equal to $0$.

However, for $x>0$,
$$
f^\prime(x) = 2x\sin (1/x) + x^2 \cos(1/x) \cdot (-1/x^2) = 2x \sin (1/x) - \cos (1/x)
$$
implies that $f^\prime$ does not converge to $0$ as $x\to +0$.

I believe this example illustrates the reason why your definitions needs to be replaced as the other answer points out.

Comment: Apologies, i realise my question missed the continuity in (1). This was an oversight and i apologise. Assuming continuity of the derivative holds for both definitions, are they equivalent, even for the compact $T$?

Comment: Read my answer carefully. f defined here is continuously differentiable on x>0.

Comment: Apologies, I realise I wasnt very clear in my last comment: I have tried to add the assumption of the derivative being continuous on the closed interval to both definitions.

Comment: Now that the first question you had is answered, I think you should post a separate question for the general T.

Comment: What I'm trying to understand is whether knowing the derivative is continuous on the compact set is equivalent to having an open superset over which the derivative is continuous

Comment: The general compact $T$ is in the original question

Comment: Yes, I understand. But I suggest you to post a separate question so that you can receive an appropriate answer since the first question is already answered by the other answer (and you should accept the answer for her/him). The second question is more involved so it deserves to have a separate post.